# Using a value of an document as _id when importing this document to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to import an Object into Mongo. But when I try to use a value of the Object as _id it fails. The error i.e: "[CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "11563195" at path "_id"]" and later "[Error: document must have an _id before saving]"

What am I doing wrong ?

```
// Read and import the CSV file.
    csv.fromPath(filePath, {
        objectMode: true,
        headers: keys
    })
    .on('data', function (data) {

        setTimeout(function(){

            var Obj = new models[fileName](data);
            Obj._id = Obj.SOME_ID;

            Obj.save(function (err, importedObj) {

                if (err) {

                    console.log(err);

                } else {

                    console.log('Import: OK');

                }
            });

        }, 500);
    })
```

Here is the used Schema:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var SomeSchema = new Schema(
        {
            SOME_ID: String,
            FIELD01: String,
            FIELD02: String,
            FIELD03: String,
            FIELD04: String,
            FIELD05: String,
            FIELD06: String,
            FIELD07: String,
            FIELD08: String,
            FIELD09: String,
            FIELD10: String,
            FIELD11: String,
            FIELD12: String,
            FIELD13: String
        },
        {
            collection: 'SomeCollection'
        });

module.exports = mongoose.model('SomeCollection', SomeSchema);
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `"11563195"` is not a valid value for ObjectID

Comment: What's the schema for `Obj`? And what's the data you're trying to save here?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's a schema I created to import data from CSV, all strings. And I would need to use a string i.e "11563195" as _id. Isn't it possible ?

Comment: Should be possible. Must be you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Need to see your mongoose schema.

Comment: @lostintranslation updated the question with schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default mongoose is validating that the _id field is a MongoId.  If you want to store something other than a MongoId in the _id field you will need to give the _id field a different type.

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

Comment: Great exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.